# How to present hierarchical data using tableviewcontroller in ios

Tags: ios

Am a newbie to ios development.

Building a simple app that lets users navigate hierarchical data. For e.g., navigating directory structures.

We built a TreeViewController and set the data source to the first level. What's not clear is to how to initialize the same controller and push it so that the next level can be represented.

I tried the following:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [self storyboard];
CVBrowseViewController *selfController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"browseTable"];


//Push the new table view on the stack
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self animated:YES];

[selfController setFolderList:children];
```

However, this throws an error: Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self animated:YES];
```

should be:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:selfController animated:YES];
```

Comment: that was perfect. Fixed my issue.

Comment: I'd suggest you don't use the word `self` in variable names, it's likely to mislead..